# Mocking class with static members

Tags: java, mockito, junit4, powermock

I need to write a junit4 test where I need to mock a class with a static member which produces `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` if not mocked.

```
ClassToMock classToMock = mock(ClassToMock.class);
PowerMockito.whenNew(ClassToMock.class).withArguments(any()).thenReturn(classToMock);
StaticMember staticMember = mock(StaticMember.class);
PowerMockito.whenNew(StaticMember.class).withArguments(any()).thenReturn(staticMember);
```

And this is what my class looks like:

```
public class ClassToMock {
    public static final StaticMember staticMember_ = new StaticMemberDeserializer().deserialize("some argument");
}
```

Here `StaticMemberDeserializer` is a deserializer that uses some argument to create StaticMember.

Is there a way to directly mock the class `ClassToMock`? If no, what can I do to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepare class to mock

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(fullyQualifiedNames = "com.my.ClassToMock")
```

On test class level.